# Перевод из дюйм в см

Tags: c

Ввожу 5.08c. Вывод empty

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    float x1;
    char ch;
    scanf("%f%c", &x1, &ch);
    if ((x1 == 5.08) && (ch == 'c'))
        printf("%5.3f \n", x1 / 2.54);
//5.08cm = 2"
}
```

Сравниваю 5.08 и символ 'c'. В чем ошибка? Оба должны дать истину.

Comment: @marioxxx, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: окэй окэй, не знал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что (float)5.08 **не равен** (double)5.08 как это ни странно (для меня тоже).

Напишите ...(x1 == (float)5.08)... и все заработает.

Константы по умолчанию double. Вообще советую без особой нужды в экономии памяти float не пользоваться.

Comment: окэй
float = %f
double = %lf

Comment: Или так: x1 == 5.08f

Comment: Вообще дробные числа лучше сравнивать с определенной точностью, например если fabs(x1-5.08)<0.0001, то x1 равно 5.08 с точностью до 4 знака после запятой.